# What is the Eclipse External Annotation Format for Static Inner Classes?

Tags: eclipse, external-annotations

I am trying to write an Eclipse External Annotation file for the static inner class Map.Entry.  How do I do this?

I created a file named `Map$Entry.eea` in the `java/util` sub-folder under the folder where all of my External Annotation files are located.  Here are the contents of that file.

```
class java/util/Map$Entry

comparingByKey
 <K::Ljava/lang/Comparable<-TK;>;V:Ljava/lang/Object;>()Ljava/util/Comparator<Ljava/util/Map$Entry<TK;TV;>;>;
 <K::Ljava/lang/Comparable<-TK;>;V:Ljava/lang/Object;>()L1java/util/Comparator<L1java/util/Map$Entry<T1K;TV;>;>;

comparingByKey
 <K:Ljava/lang/Object;V:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Ljava/util/Comparator<-TK;>;)Ljava/util/Comparator<Ljava/util/Map$Entry<TK;TV;>;>;
 <K:Ljava/lang/Object;V:Ljava/lang/Object;>(L1java/util/Comparator<-TK;>;)L1java/util/Comparator<L1java/util/Map$Entry<TK;TV;>;>;

comparingByValue
 <K:Ljava/lang/Object;V::Ljava/lang/Comparable<-TV;>;>()Ljava/util/Comparator<Ljava/util/Map$Entry<TK;TV;>;>;
 <K:Ljava/lang/Object;V::Ljava/lang/Comparable<-TV;>;>()L1java/util/Comparator<L1java/util/Map$Entry<TK;T1V;>;>;

comparingByValue
 <K:Ljava/lang/Object;V:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Ljava/util/Comparator<-TV;>;)Ljava/util/Comparator<Ljava/util/Map$Entry<TK;TV;>;>;
 <K:Ljava/lang/Object;V:Ljava/lang/Object;>(L1java/util/Comparator<-TV;>;)L1java/util/Comparator<L1java/util/Map$Entry<TK;TV;>;>;

equals
 (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
 (L0java/lang/Object;)Z

getKey
 ()TK;
 ()TK;

getValue
 ()TV;
 ()TV;

setValue
 (TV;)TV;
 (TV;)TV;
```

Eclipse still flags a warning on `entry.getValue()` in the following code:

```
Map.Entry<@Nullable String, @NonNull Object> entry;
@NonNull Object value = entry.getValue();
```

The warning is:

```
Unsafe interpretation of method return type as '@NonNull' based on the receiver type
'Map.<@NonNull Entry<@Nullable String, @NonNull Object>>'. Type Map.Entry<K, V> doesn't seem
to be designed with null type annotations in mind.
```

Answer (score 2):

The **second line** after `getValue` must be  `()T1V;` instead of  `()TV;` for **`@NonNull`**:

```
class java/util/Map$Entry
getValue
 ()TV;
 ()T1V;
```

For `@Nullable` it would be  `()T0V;`

But because the value of a map entry can be null (*["it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to null"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-)*), there should only be a warning at `@NonNull Object value = entry.getValue();` if the type of `entry` is `Map.Entry<String, @Nullable Object>` but not if the type is `Map.Entry<String, @NonNull Object>`. To tell Eclipse that `Map.Entry` is *designed with null type annotations in mind* **the `java/util/Map$Entry.eea` file must be almost empty:**

```
class java/util/Map$Entry
```

But be careful, if you do the same for `Map` then there would be no warning for `@NonNull Object o = map.get("foo");`. You have to annotate all `@Nullable` type parameters explicitly:

```
class java/util/Map
get
 (Ljava/lang/Object;)TV;
 (Ljava/lang/Object;)T0V;
```

See also: *[Eclipse 4.6 New and Noteworthy - Improved null analysis with generics](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/jdt.php#null-analysis-generics)*

Comment: What if I have a `Map.Entry<@Nullable String, @NonNull Object> entry1;` and a `Map.Entry<@Nullable String, @Nullable Object> entry2;`.  In one case, I need `()T1V;` and in the other case I need `()T0V;`.  How do I deal with both cases?

Comment: For some Maps, null values are allowed (i.e. @Nullable V).  For other Maps, null values are not allowed (i.e. @NonNull V).  In this latter case, `Map.get()` can still return null but `Map.Entry.getValue()` will never return null.  It's too bad we cannot specify `()TV;` and Eclipse will look at the definition of `V` to determine if it is @NonNull or @Nullable.

Comment: Eclipse looks at the definition of V to determine if it is `@NonNull` or `@Nullable` if there is an external annotation file for this class but no external annotation for V of this specific method.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0) build 20170620-1800 resolved the problem.  `Map$Entry.eea` can be left as is in the question and the compiler warnings happen at the appropriate times.  If the `Map.Entry` `V` is `@NonNull` in code, then `getValue()`'s return type is `@NonNull`.  If the `Map.Entry` `V` is `@Nullable` in code, then `getValue()`'s return type is `@Nullable`.

The code in the question no longer causes a compiler warning.  The following code does (which is expected and desired).

```
Map.Entry<@NonNull String, @Nullable Object> entry;
...
entry.getValue().toString();
```